# why does LibreOffice 7.6 Writer take a long time to load?

Tags: libreoffice, 23.10

I'm running LibreOffice writer 7.6.3.2 (x86_64)
on

- Ubuntu 23.10 on Intel i5-8350U x 8
- with 32 GB of memory.
- Gnome Version 45.1
- Wayland windowing system.

This one application seems to take a long time to load. I don't need Mail Merge for other fancy features. What can I do to reduce the amount of time waiting to use LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: Is your OS installed on an SSD or a mechanical Hard Drive? How full is your storage, home much of your ram is in use? Define "long time to load." Are we talking 5 seconds, 50 seconds something else?

Comment: Is it installed as a snap or an apt package?

Comment: My OS is installed on an LVM partition of SSD storage and is 75% used having 52 GB free.

Comment: It's a snap package.

Comment: It can take 5-10 seconds to launch compared to a web browser which needs less than half a second